# Can I pass my view to FPDF to generate PDF?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, dompdf

Previously i was working with dompdf in laravel application to generate invoices.. Its taking time in generating invoices but working perfectly . Below is the code of dompdf to generate invoice by just sending the view.

```
PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
    // pass view file
view()->share('account_invoice',$account_invoice);
view()->share('account_invoice_item',$account_invoice_item);
$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin/invoice/InvoiceTemplate/template');
```

But now i am working with FPDF. Is there anything like dompdf to pass view to generate PDF.

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
View::make('admin/invoice/InvoiceTemplate/template');
```

I know my code is incorrect for FPDF but any idea how can i pass view to FPDF to generate pdf so i can send it by attactment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your goal is to dump raw html onto the pdf and have it be formatted accordingly? Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php), it might help, but I'd actually recommend a different approach.

Basically, fpdf is has no html writer built in, at least none as far as I'm aware. So I'd recommend a pdf writer with better out of the box support for your needs. Take a look at [Snappy](https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/knp-snappy) and [wkhtmltopdf](https://packagist.org/packages/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64). With Snappy and wkhtmltopdf  you can pretty easily generate pdfs on the fly by passing it html, as you're attempting to in your examples.

```
<?php

use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

$snappy = new Pdf('/path/to/wkhtmltopdf');
$snappy->generateFromHtml(View::make('admin/invoice/InvoiceTemplate/template'), '/tmp/invoice.pdf');
```